# XSLT 1.0 - Formatting numbers before sum

Tags: xslt

I have picked up an XSLT using Muench Grouping.

Here I am trying to sum up the nodes which are grouped.

Via XSL a String output can be produced into TXT which then should produce values formatted to '0.00'.
However I do not seem to be able to controll the number of decimal places in the XSL itself.

Any ideas?

Grouping:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Export/Record[generate-id() = generate-id(key('GroupEmployee',concat(EmployeeNumber,TimeStartRaw))[1])]"  >
```

Sum:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('GroupEmployee', concat(EmployeeNumber,TimeStartRaw))/Punch_nethours)"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format the number after the sum, not before - e.g.:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('GroupEmployee', concat(EmployeeNumber,TimeStartRaw))/Punch_nethours), '0.00')"/>
```

Comment: And it's done the trick, cheers!
I used a EU decimal separator in the XSLT, by changing this in the format function, it now is returning the destired result!